# Sum of a series in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is given that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=0$. Let $s_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}a_n,k=1,2,...$. Then

1. $s_k=0$ for infinitely many $k$
2. $s_k>0$ for infinitely many $k$ and $s_k<0$ for infinitely many $k$
3. It is possible that $s_k>0$ for all $k$
4. It is possible that $s_k>0$ for all but a finite number of values of $k$

In my opinion 1. and 2. are correct options but 3. is incorrect as the series is not absolutely convergent, therefore all the terms of the series are not positive. But what about 4? I strongly feel that it is incorrect. But how? Please help!

Comment: But in this case sum of the series is not $0$.

Comment: Missed that, I'll delete that comment

Comment: 4. has the same consequences as 3.; if you combine finitely many initial values of the sequence into one, the (relative/absolute) convergence does not change.

Comment: When it comes to 1., what makes you think that $s_k$ must be equal to zero even for *just one* value of $k$?

Comment: 2. need not hold. Consider $1-1+1/2-1/2+1/3-1/3+\cdots$.

Comment: For 3. look at $(1+1/2)  -1 + (1/2 - 1/3) -1/2 +(1/3 - 1/9) -1/3 +(1/4-1/27)-1/4+\cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for 3. to be satisfied.

Consider the series
$$S=
(1+1/2) -1 +(1/2-1/3) -1/2 +(1/2-1/9)-1/3+(1/4-1/27)-1/4+\cdots.
$$
(so $a_1= 1+1/2$, $a_2=-1$, $a_3=1/2-1/3$, $\ldots$).

Here

$\ \ \ \ \ s_{2n} = {1\over 2} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (1/3)^k$

and

$\ \ \ \ \ s_{2n+1} = {1\over 2} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (1/3)^k  +{1\over n+1}-(1/3)^{n } =\Bigl( {1\over2} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(1/3)^k\Bigr)+{1\over n+1}.$

Both $(s_{2n}) $ and $(s_{2n+1})$ are sequences of positive terms with limit $0$.

So, $S$ converges to $0$ and all its partial sums are positive. $S$, however, is not absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

It is "clear" that $s_k$ need not ever be equal to 0. So if justification is not asked for, things are easy. However, for certainty we need to provide an example.

It is a standard fact that the series 
$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$$
is conditionally convergent and has sum $\ln 2$. It is not hard to show that $\ln 2$ is irrational.

We modify the series so that it has sum $0$. Keep the positive terms. Replace $-\frac{1}{2}$ by $-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\ln 2}{2^1}\right)$, replace $-\frac{1}{4}$ by $-\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\ln 2}{2^2}\right)$, replace $-\frac{1}{6}$ by $-\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{\ln 2}{2^3}\right)$, and so on.

It is not difficult to show that the modified series is conditionally convergent and has sum $0$.

However, partial sums are never equal to $0$. For any partial sum other than the first is of the shape $r+s\ln 2$, where $r$ and $s$ are rational and $s\ne 0$. So any partial sum after the first is irrational, and in particular cannot be $0$.

Comment: I must say that your example is very clever. Showing that none of the partial sums is zero is really not so easy, but you used the irrationality of $\ln 2$ to make this very simple. +1

Comment: It was straightforward. Note that David Mitra's example is much better. He used it for 3), but in fact it also deals with 1).